# How can we ensure that instances of this class can be safely used by multiple threads?

Tags: java, string

This class is intended to allow users to write a series of messages, so that each message is identified with a timestamp and the name of the thread that wrote the message

```
public class Logger {
    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message) {
        contents.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
        contents.append(": ");
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        contents.append(message);
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the class collects the messages in the `StringBuilder`? There isn't any way to get the messages at the moment. And what exactly is your question?

Comment: For one, you should use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`, `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really intend to collect logs like this, the most simple approach would be to use a `synchronized` section to make sure that only one thread at a time can access the `contents` field:

```
public class Logger {

    private final StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message) {
        synchronized (contents) {
            contents.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
            contents.append('[');
            contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            contents.append("]: ");
            contents.append(message);
            contents.append("\n");
        }
    }

    public String getContents() {
        synchronized (contents) {
            return contents.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

The field should be `final` in order to safely serve as a lock.

More about `synchronized`: https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized#the-synchronized-keyword

Comment: *The field must be `final` in order to serve as a lock.* Not strictly true, but it's usually a good idea.

Comment: @shmosel True. I'll edit that out. I remember some IDE throwing errors at me if I didn't do that. :-)

Comment: IntelliJ warns about it.

Comment: If you switch to `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`, you can remove the `synchronized` block in `getContents`.

Answer (score 1):

You can constrain exclusive access to a `Logger` object by simply adding the `synchronized` keyword to each method.

```
public class Logger {

    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public synchronized void log(String message) {
        contents.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
        contents.append('[');
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        contents.append("]: ");
        contents.append(message);
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public synchronized String getContents() {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
public class Logger {

    private final StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message) {
        synchronized (this) {
            contents.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
            contents.append('[');
            contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            contents.append("]: ");
            contents.append(message);
            contents.append("\n");
        }
    }

    public String getContents() {
        synchronized (this) {
            return contents.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Newerth `synchronized T method() { ... }` is the same as `T method() { synchronized (this) { ... }}`.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right. Okay, I've learned something new. Thank you. :-)